# push another object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

**This is my code, it's not the best one, but its what I know at the moment. It's strange why everytime I push a new object into the array it doesn't enter in my layout. I haven't tried a solution with css, I think the problem is with the javascript**

```js
export default {
  data:()=>{
    return{
      cards:[
        {title: 'Azorius de volta ao topo!', subtitle: 'Baralho volta a vencer um Magic Fest Modern após longo hiato.', head: 'Modern'},
        {title: 'Pauper no Papel', subtitle: 'Wizards oficializa o formato', head: 'Pauper'},
        {title: 'Hogaak Winter', subtitle: 'Possível última semana do monstro', head: 'Modern'}
      ],
    }
  },
  components:{
    Modal
  },
  methods:{
    loadMore(){
      console.log(this.cards);
      this.cards.push({title: 'alfafa', head: 'alfafa'}) 
    }
}
}
```

```css
.footer-card{
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1a1a1a, #666666);
}
.icons{
  color: #fff !important;
}
.title{
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 12px
}
.subtitle{
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.card-zise{
  width: 21.500em !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <v-flex xs6 class="mx-auto" style="display:flex">
  <v-card
    
    class="mx-auto" style="padding: 0 0.625em"
    v-for="card in cards" :key="card"
  >
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-avatar color="grey"></v-list-item-avatar>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title class="headline">{{card.head}}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>

    <v-img
      src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/mountain.jpg"
      height="194"
    ></v-img>

    <v-card-text v-bind="cards" class="title">
      {{ card.title }} <br/>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-btn @click="loadMore()">Carregar Mais</v-btn>
```

[here is the results of the push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXMyb.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, yeah - I deleted my comment when I realized I answered a different question than this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure your problem is how you deal with uniqueness of Array items.  You are using the actual card object as the `key`.  Don't do that.  Try to pick a unique property of the element of the Object within the Array.

If there is no unique piece to it, you could potentially use the index of the Array:

```
<div v-for="(card, idx) in cards" :key="idx">{{card}}</div>
```

or just leave the `key` off:

```
<div v-for="card in cards">{{card}}</div>
```

Additionally, if your issue is that you want  to change the order of the cards, you need to adjust how you are inserting into the `cards` array.  Vue will iterate whatever you give it in the order that you provide it.  So if you want the new card to be at the top, you need to insert it in the first position.  One way to do that is to use `...` spread syntax:

```
this.cards = [{foo: "bar"}, ...this.cards];
```

Where `{foo: "bar"}` is the new Object to insert and `...this.cards` is the expansion of the Array `this.cards`.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      cards: [{
          title: 'Azorius de volta ao topo!',
          subtitle: 'Baralho volta a vencer um Magic Fest Modern após longo hiato.',
          head: 'Modern'
        },
        {
          title: 'Pauper no Papel',
          subtitle: 'Wizards oficializa o formato',
          head: 'Pauper'
        },
        {
          title: 'Hogaak Winter',
          subtitle: 'Possível última semana do monstro',
          head: 'Modern'
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore() {
      this.cards = [{
          title: 'alfafa',
          head: 'alfafa'
        },
        ...this.cards
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-for="card in cards">
      <div>{{card.head}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button @click="loadMore()">Carregar Mais</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i realize that in the answer of @sandrooco but the problem is the format os the new card object come in to my layout as u can see in my  picture he put the push in the last position, i want to put above os 3 cards, thanks for advice

Comment: i tried u soloution i'm very appreciate that but is not wok, the new card apperars in the first position , not above, i think the problem with layout =/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using an object as `key` attribute. Try it like this:

```
<v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    v-for="(card, cardIndex) in cards" :key="'card-' + cardIndex"
  >
...
</v-card>
```

Firstly like this you don't have objects as `key` and also not just a `number`.

Comment: i try this, but the push keep put the new card object in the last row of cards, its really hard to format that, and put in above the other cards. by he way thanks for advice, i dont know about using object as a key is not good

Comment: @MatheusWanderley Maybe because the subtitle is missing?

Comment: because the real problem is to render a object card, in a grid 3x3, 3 up, 3 above, and its not happens only render 3 up more 1 one up, =/